# Updating a child in Firebase Realtime Database doesn't do anything

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

When I try to update a child in Firebase Realtime Database it doesn't work. It seems as if the `set` doesn't do anything.

```
  Future<void> changeCategory(Category c){
    return remoteDataService.categoriesRefernece.child(c.id).set(c.toMap());
  }
```

There's a list of categories in the database and the method above should update it. The `toMap` method converts the `Cateory` Object into `Map<String, dynamic>` and `c.id` stores the firebase-id of the `Cateory`

Comment: Does your client have permission to write to the location in the database? If you're not sure, either check the security rules of your database, or check the logging output of your app for "permission denied" errors.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffeln the user is permitted and there is no logging output either

Comment: In that case: what happens if you write a simple hard-coded value to the location? So something like `.set("Hello")`? *If that works*, you can be quite sure the problem comes from whatever `c.toMap()` returns and would need to investigate that further (or update the question to include its code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the category in `changeCategory` didn't contain the new values so that there wasn't anything to update.